# org-contacts trying to use rows in the contacts file as org-agenda-files

Tags: org-contacts

Calling `org-contacts` and input a name, I expect in return a list of contacts matching that name. Instead, it results in emacs trying to interpret each row of my contacts file as org-agenda-files.

Example of my `contacts.org` file:

```
* John Doe
  :PROPERTIES:
  :BIRTHDAY: 2016-02-13
  :END:
```

Setup in init.el:

```
(use-package org-contacts
  :ensure t
  :custom
  (org-contacts-files "~/contacts.org")
  )
```

I tried debugging, and in my limited knowledge of debugging I see at a point a function called org-read-agenda-files (or similar) getting the first row of my contact files, the header, and append it to the path where my init.el is (.emacs.d) and trying to read it as a file:

```
Non-existent agenda file c:/Users/c740/OneDrive/org/.emacs.d/#+STARTUP: overview.  [R]emove from list or [A]bort?
```

Note that hitting `R` the contacts.org file is modified: emacs delete the entire first row, and then proceed with the second non-empty row and try to interpret as an agenda file, and so on.

I run emacs on MS Windows: `GNU Emacs 28.2 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2022-09-13`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org-contacts-files` is supposed to be a *list* of files. Try:

```
...
:custom
(org-contacts-files ("~/contacts.org"))
...
```

I'm not sure whether `use-package` wants the list quoted or not.

EDIT: As the OP points out in the comment, the list needs to be quoted:

```el
...
:custom
(org-contacts-files '("~/contacts.org"))
...
```

Comment: The list shall be quoted: `(org-contacts-files ' ("~/contacts.org"))`